# Cookie Timeout Length

Tags: javascript, cookies

I need a way to make a cookie last hours instead of days.

My cookie handler `function` sets the cookie's name, value, and expiry time like so:

```
function keeperSetCookie(name, value, expires) {
   document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/" +
   ((expires == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString());
}
```

I already know that I need to change the `expires` variable from `null` to an actual value, but I don't know what value to set.

What value should the `expires` variable be set to, to change the expire time to two hours?

*Note:* The code works fine, I just want to set the cookie's expiry time.

Comment: Poor choice of duplicate, OP would have to dig out the reason from inside a larger cookie script. I already saw that answer and was not impressed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass `new Date(Date.now()+2*60*60*1000)` as 3rd arg which will set a date 2 hours in the future

```
keeperSetCookie("cookiename","cookieValue",new Date(Date.now()+2*60*60*1000));
```

Comment: Would the 24 make the cookie last two days or two hours?

Comment: I mean I need to for two hours.  Was it the original or the current.

Comment: 60*60*1000 is 1 hour. *24 is one day. *2*24 is two days

Comment: Downvoters would be ever so useful when leaving comments but annoying pests when not.